# I can not load excel file data into my database

Tags: php, mysql

The goal is to recover data from an Excel file and load its data into my database.
with a `var_dump` I see my data but impossible to put in the database.

**load.php**

```php
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
use App\Base;

if( isset( $_POST["import"] ) ) {
   $fileName = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
   var_dump( $fileName );
   if( $_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0 ) {

      $file = fopen( $fileName, "r" );
      while( ( $column = fgetcsv( $file, 1024, "," ) ) !== false ) {
         try {
               $sqlInsert = new Base( 'gac' );
               $data      = $sqlInsert->query( "INSERT INTO testo (nom,prenom) values (" . $column[0] . ", " . $column[1] . ")" );
               $result    = $data->execute( array(
                                'nom' => $column[0],
                                'prenom' => $column[1] ) );
               var_dump( $data );
            } catch( Exception $e ) {
               die( 'Erreur: ' . $e->getMessage() );
            }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to put placeholders instead of values in the query

Comment: Thanks @Dharman i found solution

Comment: You could answer your own question if you think it would help others with similar problems in future.